Why does my modifier deform the object in an unusual way?
I want to deform my cylinder using a modifier Simple Deform. Everything worked well in the video, but in my case, the modifier deformed my cylinder in a strange way and I don't understand why. I've tried to apply modifier to new Cylinder, but it works the same way.  The first screenshot - video, second screenshot - mine.



First make sure your rotation is applied. Ctrl+A > Rotation. If that doesn't help use a target object for the axis and try rotating it by 90 degrees on one of the non-deformation axes. This is usually caused by some weird overlap between the deform axis and the objects transform axes. So like if you're bending on the Y-axis, rotate the Axis object by 90 on the Z or X axes. It takes experimentation.

Probably needs to apply scale.

It is definitely the scale in this case, not the rotation. The bend works in the same direction as the reference but looks stretched.

It looks like you scaled the cylinder in Object Mode and did not apply the scale afterwards. Here is a comparison, both cylinders have the exact same settings in the Simple Deform modifier:

The left one looks similar to yours (only that my origin and the bend are centered other than the objects in the question), the right one looks like in the tutorial. To fix your cylinder, just press Ctrl+A > Apply Scale. Afterwards they both look the same:

I would recommend you pay close attention to what they are doing in the tutorial. They either scaled the cylinder in Object Mode and applied the scale afterwards like I showed here, or they scaled it in Edit Mode. Changes you make in Edit Mode are not affecting the object transformations so they do not have to be applied.

Thank you all for your assistance. I applied Scale and my problem was solved

@dmitryrubanov You're welcome. Please see: What should I do if someone answers my question?
